# Android Pre Dex: [viewpagerındicator-24f452b776498fe21d4656d33451f239.jar] no classfiles specified

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I moved my project from eclipse to idea 13 and I face this error

```
Android Pre Dex: [viewpagerındicator-24f452b776498fe21d4656d33451f239.jar] no classfiles specified
```

after building the project , I have no idea about the reason ?

I use this line to import the project

```
 <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1" level="project" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the viewpagerindicator as a module without using maven and this solve my problem